# Pagination like (Items per page: 25|50|75|100) in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, pagination, laravel-5.5

How to display specified number of records on web page?

Like : Items per page: 25 | 50 | 75 |100
 If I select 25 then 25 records should be displayed.. 
I want this in laravel 5.5.. can anyone help me?

Comment: Just pass the number of items per page to the paginate method, for example  `->paginate(75)`. The [Pagination Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/pagination) are pretty clear about that.

Comment: But I want this,->( Items per page: 25 | 50 | 75 |100)  view in my index.blade.php and in my index function of page controller

Comment: Send the number via the request query string. For example: `yourapp.com/users?perPage=100` and in your controller action just fetch that from the request `Users::paginate(request()->get('perPage', 25);`. This will get the `100` value from the request and if no `perPage` paramater was passed, it will default to `25`. You also might want to inject the request into your controller action method (not use the `request()` helper) and in order to do that you might want to read the [HTTP Requests Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/pagination).

Comment: But what should I do in index.blade.php?? Should I use any if else?

Comment: You're offering very little context of what your current code looks like, so you might want to edit your question to include your current code so we can offer more accurate advice.

Answer (score 2):

There is no default functionality for per page in Laravel till 5.7. So, you need to add some custom functionality.

Use get parameter where you paginate your record like this:

```
public function get_users(Request $request) {
    return view('users', Users::paginate($request->get('per_page', 25)));
}
```

And send `per_page` parameter from view.

There are several ways to send `per_page` parameter from view.

I am using LaravelCollective 5.4 for this purpose https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.4/html#drop-down-lists:

```
{!! Form::open([ 'url' => route('users'), 'method' => 'get' ]) !!}
    {!! Form::select( 'per_page', [ '25' => '25', '50' => '50', '75' => '75', '100' => '100'], '25', array('onchange' => "submit()") ) !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```